# Difference between Core Animation and UIKit Dynamics in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, core-animation, uikit-dynamics

I have been recently working with `UIKit Dynamics` and its great! However I have come across that `Core Animation` also offers similar functions as that of `UIKit Dynamics`. Could someone help me differentiate between these two.
Basically I need to differentiate when to use `Core Animation` and when to use `UIKit Dynamics.`

Comment: you can checkout the apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html & https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: UIKit Dynamics has physics capability and useful in developing games. Its quite similar to frameworks like cocos2D and it is available since iOS 7.0. But CoreAnimation is simple animations that you need in your application like fadein, fadeout, flip etc.. This is basic difference, though there are lot many differences too, read documentation..

Comment: CoreAnimation is *simple*??? It's vast and complex, not simple.

Answer (score 5):

`UIKit Dynamics` allows for the animation of user interface elements (typically view items) to be implemented within a user interface, often in response to user interaction. In order to fully understand the concepts behind `UIKit Dynamics`, it helps to visualize how real world objects behave.

The `UIKit Dynamics` implementation comprises four key elements consisting of a dynamic animator, a set of one or more dynamic behaviors, one or more dynamic items and a reference view.

The `dynamic items` are the view elements within the user interface that are to be animated in response to specified dynamic behaviors. A dynamic item is any view object that implements the UIDynamicItem protocol which includes the `UIView` and `UICollectionView` classes and any subclasses thereof (such as `UIButton` and `UILabel`). Any custom view item can be made to work with `UIKit Dynamics` by making it conform to the `UIDynamicItem protocol`.

For more Information about `UIKit Dynamic` please [Click here](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/introduction-to-uikit-dynamics/)

Click below links For Core animation :

[Link1](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-1)

[Link2](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-2)

[Link3](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-3)

[Link4](http://nachbaur.com/blog/core-animation-part-4)